# By the time I get to Khulna this evening, I _____________ more than three hundred miles

Tags: tense, verbs, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

*This question came in the Dhaka university admission exam in 2013-14*

Q) By the time I get to Khulna this evening, I _____________ more than three hundred miles.

(a) will driving

(b) will be driving

(c) will have been driving

(d) will have been driven

I think that all of the options are incorrect. The correct option is "will have driven". Am I correct?

Comment: [On this page](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-6.html) "by the time" is explained perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although **will have driven** is the obvious answer,

0ption (c) is possible if you were the driver,

and Option (d) if you were a passenger.

As with similar queries relating to Dhaka University, one has reason to doubt the competence of those framing the questions.

Comment: Yes, The English language is interesting. These guys seem to think “I want to express X” and a sentence is correct - to them - if it expresses X. But they don’t seem to realise that they often show _correct_ sentences with a different meaning. Like (d) which is a perfectly fine sentence that expresses clearly that you were the passenger (or someone kidnapped in the boot of the car).